# Passing variables in Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables

I'm New to powershell I want to know how to pass a variable(with Space) using commandline.

My variable is : ZCMASS LOS A

When I execute this only ZCMASS is getting printed.I want the whole variable.

Script:

```
powershell -command "& "C:\scripts\tivoli\mail\ZCMASS_TEST.ps1"" ZCMASS LOS A
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell uses spaces as a separator in commands.  Parameters containing spaces must normally be enclosed in quotation marks.  An alternative to that is the back tic (`).  In a case like this, where you are in quotation marks already, the back tic can come in handy.

Is this what you want?

```
powershell -command "& {'C:\scripts\tivoli\mail\ZCMASS_TEST.ps1' ZCMASS` LOS` A}"
```

Also, if you are trying to pass this variable to a script, instead of executing as if it were typed at the command prompt, you might be looking for the -file parameter instead of -command as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339435/how-to-pass-path-with-spaces-to-script).

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I used the back tic(`) and it worked.
Below Is the script that worked:
powershell -command "& "C:\scripts\tivoli\mail\ZCMASS_TEST.ps1"" `ZCMASS` LOS` A`